# Scroll with stylus on surface pro

Tags: scrolling, microsoft-surface-pro

I just purchased a Surface Pro 2. I tried to scroll using the stylus (on a chrome page for example). The problem is that I'm getting an icon with the shortcut I just used but my scroll has no effect.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Does your finger work?

Comment: Sorry but what does fringe mean ? I'm not english :s

Comment: It was a typo clearly.  I fixed it before you even made that comment though.

Comment: Oh sorry. yes my finger works great but when i'm trying to scroll with the stylus I'm an icon of scroll is displayed but it doesn't scroll.

Comment: Have you updated all device drivers.  I would try installing the current drivers for the [device](http://us.wacom.com/en/feeldriver/) be sure you also install all released updates for the system.  Additional verify your using Windows 8.1 with all released updates installed.

Comment: It still doesn't work.

Comment: To be more correct, on ly the scroll shortcut doesn't work.

Comment: What function do you have the button assigned to? Are you accidentally pressing it?

Comment: The button opens the context menu on touch. I'm not pessing it. For "proof" the icone of the scroll is displayed, but nothing happens..